# c# inheritance trouble. I can't see a method in my inheritance chain

Tags: c#, inheritance, c#-4.0

I think I may have c# inheritance issue.

When ran, the code below produces a, "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred" error message.

When debugging in Visual Studio, I see that the variable "path" is always null in my "Finder" class.

It doesn't seem to be even getting to the "GetUrl" method in the the "WebConnector" class, which probably explains the null error message I get, but I'm not sure why it's not able to get to that method in the first place.

Am I inheriting the base class wrong?

Thanks!

WebConnector.cs:

```
public class WebConnector
{
    public String GetUrl(string Id, String baseUrl)
    {
        string right = String.Format("/a('{0}')/b", Id);
        return baseUrl + right; 
    }
```

baseClass.cs:

```
public class BaseClass
{

    public WebConnector Connector { get; set; }

}
```

Finder.cs:

```
public class Finder : BaseClass
{

    public String GetBuild()
    {
        var path = Connector.GetUrl(Id, baseUrl);  //always null??
    }

}
```

Comment: And where or how do you set `Connector`?

Comment: `Finder.Connector` is never instantiated, so you can't call `GetUrl` on it. If `GetUrl` was static, then you could, as it wouldn't require an instance of `Connector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an instance of `WebConnector`. You could create this in your `BaseClass` constructor:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass() 
    {
       Connector = new WebConnector();
    }

    public WebConnector Connector { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you never initialize `Connector`.  There are 2 solutions to this problem:

First, you can make your `GetUrl` function static, because it doesn't use anything within the object itself:

```
public static String GetUrl(string Id, String baseUrl)
```

In this case, you wouldn't even need a reference to the class, so you could completely remove `Connector` from `BaseClass` and change your `GetBuild` function like so:

```
var path = WebConnector.GetUrl(Id, baseUrl);
```

However, I don't think this is the behaviour you're looking for, since `WebConnector` sounds like it will be something you want to actually initialize at some point.

You can initialize it 2 ways, and either will work, so take your pick.

First, you can modify your `Finder` class to include a constructor which initializes `Connector`:

```
public class Finder : BaseClass
{
    public Finder() 
    {
        Connector = new WebConnector();
    }

    public String GetBuild()
    {
        var path = Connector.GetUrl(Id, baseUrl);
    }
}
```

The other option is to handle this in `BaseClass`, by modifying it like so:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public WebConnector Connector { get; set; }

    public BaseClass(){
        Connector = new WebConnector();
    }
}
```

If you go this route, `Connector` will always be initialized as soon as `Finder` is called, and you could actually use `Connector` in the `Finder` constructor (C# always builds from most-base class to most-derived class).